# What's the difference between feeling nauseated and feeling detestable?

Tags: vocabulary, emotions

[This page](https://flowingdata.com/2020/03/20/wheel-of-emotional-words/) lists a range of emotions in a wheel:

[image: Emotional wheel]

There are a number of nuances at the edges that I'm not quite clear on but one in particular stood out: When feeling "awful", what's the difference between feeling nauseated and feeling detestable?

Edit to add dictionary definitions:

- **detestable**: deserving intense dislike.
- **nauseated**: affect with nausea. fill (someone) with disgust.

Obviously, these definitions don't clarify the differences between the 2 emotions. At least not to me. Are they even emotions like the user nnnnnn commented?

Comment: Have you looked at the respective dictionary definitions of those words?

Comment: *Detestable* isn't really an emotion, it means "deserving to be detested". I guess someone could feel that they are abominable and that others *should* detest them, but I still wouldn't name that emotion "detestable".

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the downvotes. Makes me feel really _welcome_ here. /s

Comment: I am nauseated by detestable people.

Comment: (That wheel is out of alignment.)

Comment: I think detestable is when you feel so awful you wanna give up, and nauseated is when you wanna throw up.

Comment: I'm not surprised that you're not quite clear on some of the words in the outer circle in relation to the word in the second circle with which they are associated. Given that they have restricted themselves to two words in each association some ot the so-called synonyms are really strange choices.

Answer (score 1):

"Nausea" is a very specific word: it's the unpleasant sensation that you feel when you may be about to vomit. To be nauseated is to have that particular unpleasant feeling.

I don't think "detestable" is actually a feeling. If someone said "I feel detestable", I wouldn't know what they meant. My two guesses would be that they mean either "I feel like other people detest me or ought to detest me", or "I have a detestable feeling—a horrible feeling that I detest".